# Inspect lambda code from Python interpreter

Tags: python, lambda, ipython, inspect

this simple python program that is extracted from more complex codebase:

```
#insp.py
import inspect
L = lambda x: x+1
print("L(10)=" + str(L(10)))
code = inspect.getsource(L)
print(code)
```

works if i run it from the command line as:

```
$ python insp.py
```

If I copy and paste each line in the python interpreter it fails:

```
d:\>python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect
>>> L = lambda x: x+1
>>> print("L(10)=" + str(L(10)))
L(10)=11
>>> code = inspect.getsource(L)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\Users\Cimino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\inspect.py", line 944, in getsource
    lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
  File "d:\Users\Cimino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\inspect.py", line 931, in getsourcelines
    lines, lnum = findsource(object)
  File "d:\Users\Cimino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib\inspect.py", line 762, in findsource
    raise OSError('could not get source code')
OSError: could not get source code
```

Note that using IPython instead of the plain Python interpreter, it works!

Does anybody know why?

I use Python 3.5 32 bits under Windows7.

Comment: I'd guess this is because the inspect module actually goes and looks for a source file which the interpreter tracks. Note the interface can also give you line numbers, comments before the definition, etc. None of these exist when you're in the REPL. I imagine IPython does some magic to ensure inspect works correctly in the interactive case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in IPython because it caches each and every command you enter there using [linecache](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) module.

For example:

```
$ ipy  ## Equivalent to ipython --classic
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-9d7b17ad5387>", line 1, in <module>
    print a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Notice the `<ipython-input-1-9d7b17ad5387>` part here, this is something specific to IPython. In normal Python shell you would see `<stdin>`:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Now let's run your code:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> L = lambda x: x+1
>>> code = inspect.getsource(L)
```

Time to find out the filename related to `L`:

```
>>> L.func_code.co_filename
'<ipython-input-2-0c0d6f325784>'
```

Now let's see if we have the source in `linecache.cache` for this file:

```
>>> import linecache
>>> linecache.cache[L.func_code.co_filename]
(18, 1481047125.479239, [u'L = lambda x: x+1\n'], '<ipython-input-2-0c0d6f325784>')
```

So, using this information IPython is able to find the required source but Python shell doesn't because it is not storing any.

---

The related details about how `inspect` gets the source can be found in [`getsourcefile`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/inspect.py#l439) and [`findsource`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/inspect.py#l517) functions in the source code.

Comment: For Python 3: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py

Comment: Is there a workaround to this? What if we would like to build ast's interactively from python objects in the interpreter? Seems like a severe limitation!